# Array shows but subarray shows "illegal string offset" error - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Here's a sample of

```
$arr = json_decode('{"people":[
{
  "id": "8080",
  "content": "foo",
  "member": [123, 456],
  "interval": 7
},
{ 
  "id": "8097",
  "content": "bar",
  "member": [1234, 4567],
  "interval": 7
}


]}', true);

$searchId = 123;
$results = array_filter($arr['people'], function($people) use ($searchId) {
    return in_array($searchId, $people['member']);
});

$final = json_encode($results);

echo $final;
```

This prints [{"id":"8080","content":"foo","member":[123,456],"interval":7}]

But when I try to get the specific value of an element (e.g. "content"), it shows me an illegal string offset error

```
echo $final["content"];
```

What should I be doing instead to show the value of "content"? (which would be "foo" in this case)

Comment: `$final` is a JSON string. If you want the value of `content` then `echo $results[0]['content'];`

Comment: `echo $final["content"];` can not work because $final is string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually , you don't need to `$final = json_encode($results);`

directly output to

```
echo $results[0]["content"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo $final["content"];` to `echo $results[0]["content"];`